# How do i setState in multidimensional array of objects via functional component

Tags: reactjs

How do I change the value of inCart to true
 based on id,
like i have a function that will provide a id , and base that id i want to change the first objects inCart value to true or the 2nd object inCart value

I tried like this:

```
setInfo({ info[id].inCart: true })
/*Note: id is a parameter that hold the number like 1 or 2 etc*/

const [info, setInfo] = useState([
        {
            id: 1,
            title: "Google Pixel - Black",
            inCart: false
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            title: "Samsung S7",
            inCart: false,
        }  
])
```

Comment: What is the `id` in `info[id]` refer to??Index or the id of Object

Comment: i am using id as index to refer that object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the reference, mutate it and return a shallow copy of your state.

```
const [info, setInfo] = useState([
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Google Pixel - Black',
    inCart: false
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Samsung S7',
    inCart: false
  }
]);

const idToChange = getId();

setInfo(info => {
  const matchingCart = info.find(cart => card.id === idToChange);
  matchingCart.inCart = !matchingCart.inCart;
  return [...info];
});
```

Comment: Generally, I use `map` and return a new array but I also like this logic if you need to mutate your state in your control. Maybe there could be an explanation of why we return a shallow copy of our state since if we don't do that react don't rerender the component.